# Finding independence of X and Y from joint pdf

Tags: probability, independence, hypergeometric-function

Two cards are drawn at random without replacement from an ordinary deck. Let X be the number of hearts and Y the number of black cards obtained.

I know the joint pdf is f(x,y) = $f(x,y) = \frac{ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 13 \\ x \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 26\\ y\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 13\\ 2-x-y \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)}{ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 52 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)}$

with marginal pdf's of $f(x) = \frac{\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 13 \\ x \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 39 \\ 2-x \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) }{ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 52 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)}$ and $f(y) = \frac{\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 26 \\ y \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 26 \\ 2-y \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) }{ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 52 \\ 2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)}$.

Are X and Y independent?

Comment: Obviously not.  If $X≥1$ then $Y$ can't be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

No they arent, if they were independent then we know that 
$f_{XY}= f_x f_y$

This is not the case here

In fact the value of X and Y are dependent because looking at the pdf, we can see that if $X>1$, then $Y<1$ as well